# Удаление из списка названий из двух слов

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, list

Задание заключается в удалении из списка названий состоящих из двух слов.

Почему в моем решении название "Пиковая дама" остается в списке? Объясните как преобразовать код, чтобы решить задачу.

```
lst = ['Муму', 'Евгений Онегин', 'Сияние', 'Мастер и Маргарита', 'Пиковая дама', 'Колобок']
i = 0
while i < len(lst):
    print(lst[i])
    if ' ' in lst[i]:
        lst.remove(lst[i])
    i += 1
print(*lst)
```

Вывод после запуска программы:
`Муму Сияние Пиковая дама Колобок`